# How to disable all input with same class based on it's value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple inputs of type number have same class

```
 <input type="number" class="InsideInvoice" value="@item.InsideQuantity" />
```

I want to disable each input with class "InsideInvoice" if it's value 0

I tried:

```
$(".InsideInvoice").attr('disabled', this.val(0))
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the class and **[attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** to first find all the matching elements and then set the `disabled` attribute with the `.attr()` method.

```js
$("input.InsideInvoice[value=0]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="InsideInvoice" value="5">
<input type="number" class="InsideInvoice" value="0">
<input type="number" class="InsideInvoice" value="10">
<input type="number" class="InsideInvoice" value="0">
```